# Difference between 'Turn up' and 'Turn in'

Tags: difference

I want to know if we can use 'Turn up' or 'Turn in' the conversation interchangeably. What is the basic difference (if any)..

Comment: This question could be improved with an example of how you want to use "turn up" and "turn in".  Also, have you looked for these phrasal verbs in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

"Turn up" most often means to increase something. It drives from the idea of turning up the volume on a radio or stereo. Another common meaning is to appear unexpectedly.

"Turn in" most often means to go to bed, or to submit a document or paper.

Of course either one can be used in a completely literal sense meaning to physically turn oneself or something in a direction that is either upwards or inward.

They are not interchangeable.